# Geoserver: Increase the precision of the json return of WPS call

Tags: geoserver, geojson, wps

I'm calling the geo:centroid WPS process from Geoserver. If I set the output type to "application/json" the returned values has only 4 digits after the dot (e.g xx.xxxx), but if I set the output type to "text/xml" the returned values has more digits after the dot (e.g xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).
My question is how to make the "application/json" returned values have more precisions (more digits after the dot).

Here is an example:

1- application/json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>geo:centroid</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>geom</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json">
            <![CDATA[
        {
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        0,
        0
      ],
      [
        10.25124,
        0.257741
      ],
      [
        10.578814,
        10.255447
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
]]>
        </wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

it returns

```
{
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    7.7375,
    2.6609
  ]
}
```

2- text/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>geo:centroid</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>geom</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json">
            <![CDATA[
        {
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        0,
        0
      ],
      [
        10.25124,
        0.257741
      ],
      [
        10.578814,
        10.255447
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
]]>
        </wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

it returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsDimension="2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <gml:pos>
        7.737501114169446 2.6609131596654136
    </gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to modify [GeoJSONPPIO](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/extension/wps/wps-core/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wps/ppio/GeoJSONPPIO.java) to make use of the same [roundedNumber](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/json/GeoJSONBuilder.java#L180) method as [GeoJSONBuilder](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/json/GeoJSONBuilder.java) does.

Usual [guidelines](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/introduction/gettinginvolved.html) apply.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to define the decimal precision on GeoServer configuration.

Configuration -> Global -> Decimal Precision

Answer (score 1):

[image: Geoserver UI]

Settings Section -> Global -> Number of decimals -> Enter your desired precision